# Too much fertiliser for tomatos? I live in Sydney, Australia

Tags: tomatoes

A few days ago I added fertiliser to my tomatos.  Now they have started growing erratically, is this normal?  Because this is my first time growing them, I live in Sydney, Australia

[image: Tomato plant]

Comment: Define “erratically” please? Do you mean a growth spurt or something else? Can you tell us a bit more about where/how you are growing them? As in indoors or outdoors, from seed or bought as small plants…?